# Calculating a positive semi-definite complex valued matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $p,q,c$ and $d$ be complex numbers in the unit disk. I'm reading a paper that requires  the following matrix
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&1&1\\ 1&\frac{1-|p|^2}{1-|c^2|}& \frac{1-p\overline{q}}{1-c\overline{d}}\\
    1&\frac{1-q\overline{p}}{1-d\overline{c}}& \frac{1-|q|^2}{1-|d|^2}
    \end{bmatrix}$$
to be positive semi-definite. The author then says that this is equivalent to the minors being nonnegative. That is:

1. $|c|\geq |p|$
2. $|d|\geq |q|$
3. $\Big|\frac{c-d}{1-c\overline{d}}\Big|\geq\Big|\frac{pd-qc}{c\overline{d}-p\overline{q}}\Big| $

I'm trying to analyze a similar matrix, and I do not understand how the author gets the the last inequality from the matrix. Since $P$ is Hermitian, we need all principle minors to be nonnegative. So I see how the first 2 inequalities come about. However, when I do the last minor, I get
$$ \frac{1-|p|^2}{1-|c^2|}\frac{1-|q|^2}{1-|d^2|}\geq \frac{|1-p\overline{q}|^2}{|1-c\overline{d}|^2}.$$ Using the identity
$$ 1-\Big|\frac{c-d}{1-c\overline{d}}\Big|^2=\frac{(1-|c|^2)(1-|d|^2)}{|1-c\overline{d}|^2} $$
I get that the inequality above becomes
$$\Big|\frac{c-d}{1-c\overline{d}}\Big|^2\geq \frac{|p-q|^2}{|1-p\overline{q}|^2}.$$ Even after taking square roots, my inequality is different then the authors 3rd inequality. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $p=q=c=\frac12$ and $d=-\frac12$.
$P=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&1&1\\ 1&1& \frac35\\
    1&\frac35&1
    \end{bmatrix}$ is positive semi-definite. However, $\left|\frac{c-d}{1-c\overline{d}}\right|=\frac45<1=\left|\frac{pd-qc}{c\overline{d}-p\overline{q}}\right|$. So there is something wrong with the author's claim as you described.

On the other hand, it looks your computation is correct.